# What are the features that you should look for when buying a hydroponic system?

Tags: strawberries, hydroponic

I'm interested in growing strawberries using [hydroponics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics). I have read up and understand that there are several types of hydroponic systems, like deep water cultivation, ebb and flow, [aeroponic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroponics), and drip feed, etc. What qualities or features should I look for when buying a hydroponic system? I'm a beginner and would like to keep the cost low.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are a beginner and are looking for the cheapest setup I would just say do it yourself.  Build something from scratch from an online tutorial.  [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Hydroponics/) has numerous tutorials on different setups and the costs associated to them.

I found that the [Hydroponics at Home and for Beginners](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hydroponics---at-Home-and-for-Beginners/) article may be right down your alley.  Also the [Hydroponic Food Factory](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hydroponic-Food-Factory/) has been used to grow strawberries (based on images posted).

If price is a greater factor than the actual process maybe you would like a new home project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'll take a look when it isn't so ridiculously late, and hopefully mark the question as closed. :)

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [Backyard Aquaponics Forum](http://www.backyardaquaponics.com/forum/) - it's not exactly hydroponics but it is a great resource and a lot of the principles carry over. The DIY section is awesome there and the community is great too!

Answer (score 3):

I'm with Seanland.  I did a DWC setup for the price of a 5-gallon bucket with a lid, a few feet of ait hose, 4 small pots, an air pump and a water rock.  I probably spent about $45 but you could knock a few dollars of that by using a normal bucket and drilling holes for the pots yourself(I bought this just in peices as they did not have the kit at my local store http://www.htgsupply.com/products/bubble-boy-four-banger-dwc).  You will also need to buy nutrients as your grow medium is no longer feeding the plant.  I prefer Coco because it is cheap and hold water really well but hydroton is also cheap and effective.